# How to Join JavaScript array of string

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array of string variable object in this format:

`["QA testing promotion ", " Twitter  ", "Facebook ", "Test"]`

I need to convert it into:

```
"QA-testing-promotion-Twitter-Facebook-Test"
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: `["QA testing promotion ", " Twitter  ", "Facebook ", "Test"].join(' ').split(' ').filter(function(item) {return item.length > 0}).join('-')`, logic: 1. join to get a big string. 2. split by `' '`, 3. filter out empty strings 4. join again, this time, by `-`.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Thanks to [@torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo)'s advice, we can use `/\s+/` to split the concatenated string by 1 or more spaces, thus avoid the `.filter` part of my original answer, then the code would be:

```js
var result = 
     ["QA testing promotion ", " Twitter ", "Facebook ", "Test"]
      .join(' ')                                                // concate to get full string
      .split(/\s+/)                                        // split by `1 or more` space to create a new array.
      .join('-');                                             // join them again with '-'

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why not split by `/\s+/` to avoid having to do the filter?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm not familiar with regex, thanks for the advice, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just join the whole array with space and replace all non word items with dash.

```js
document.write(
    ["QA testing promotion ", " Twitter ", "Facebook ", "Test"]
    .join(' ')
    .replace(/\W+/gi, '-')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `.trim()` method for strings and `.forEach()` function for arrays to accomplish this:

```js
var result = "";
["QA testing promotion ", " Twitter  ", "Facebook ", "Test"].forEach(function (element, index, array) {
    array[index] = (element.trim()).replace(/ /g, "-");
    if(index > 0) {
        result += "-" + array[index];  
    } else {
        result += array[index];  
    }
});

document.querySelector("#result").textContent = result;
```

```css
#result {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<label>Result</label>
<div id="result"></div>
```